# New to ruby. Using baserails. Experencing problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have been recently trying to learn ruby by using **ruby on rails** with baserails. Everything was fine until I got in the spot in the tutorial where there wasn't much guidance on how to install **s3** using paperclip the tutorial was for dropbox. I am so lost and have been getting errors for 2 days. I have researched this issue alot, but with my limited knowledge I am having a hard time understanding it. I know my issue is a paperclip/s3 issue. I have all my gems up to to date. Could someone please work with me and help guide me in fixing my issue. Here is my `listings_controller.fb` file. Line 66 gives me this error.

> uninitialized constant ListingsController::Listing.

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /listings
  # GET /listings.json
  def index
    @listings = Listing.all
  end

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /listings/new
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /listings
  # POST /listings.json
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /listings/1
  # DELETE /listings/1.json
  def destroy
    @listing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listings_url, notice: 'Listing was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_listing
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image)
    end
end
______________Terminal_______________-
Started GET "/listings/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-09 21:36:39 +0900
Processing by ListingsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

> NameError (uninitialized constant ListingsController::Listing):
>
> app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:67:in `set_listing'   Rendering
>   /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb
>   within rescues/layout   Rendering
>   /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
>   Rendered
>   /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
>   (5.2ms)   Rendering
>   /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb   Rendered
>   /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.3ms)   Rendering
>   /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
>   Rendered
>   /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
>   (1.3ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/chrisdionne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb
>   within rescues/layout (161.7ms)

Comment: Is your index method working? stacktrace says Rails is trying to find Listing under ListingsController module

Comment: Is your Listing model loaded? Try a rails console and see if the model is available

Comment: Hey Chris, Alex here from BaseRails. Your error message doesn't seem to be related to paperclip or S3 - can you tell me what changes you made before experiencing this error? The first thing I'd recommend is restarting your Rails server, but beyond that it's hard to say without seeing your code. There's more info on how to set up paperclip with S3 in the discussion thread [here](https://baserails.com/courses/etsydemo/set-up-dropbox) and if you're still having trouble, just post a comment there and I'll be happy to help.